# Not found page and default home page always redirect to home - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this code and always that I put a non existing route it  redirects to home. I want that when a non existing route is enter redirects to `/404` and when nothing or `/` is enter it redirects to Home.

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/badges" component={Badges} />
                <Route exact path="/badges/new" component={NewBadge} />
                <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
                <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
            </Switch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the exact prop in your Home route.

```
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I have to manually push to history in useEffect()

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `<Route>` component without providing `path` that should redirect to `404` one.

Try the following:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/badges" component={Badges} />
    <Route exact path="/badges/new" component={NewBadge} />
    <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Using 'exact' in the Home route works for me. This answer doesn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Replacing `component={404}` with `component={NotFound}` also works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/badges" component={Badges} />
    <Route exact path="/badges/new" component={NewBadge} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```